# Problema ao enviar email AWS

Tags: email, amazon-aws, route

Eu tenho dois domínios, `.com` e `.com.br`, para o domínio `.com` todos os *e-mails* enviados e recebidos estão tudo certo. Porém se eu enviar *e-mail* para o `.com.br` o *e-mail* volta.

Por exemplo, `contato@meudominio.com`, esse eu recebo normalmente, agora se colocar `contato@meudominio.com.br`, esse *e-mail* volta.

Não sei como devo proceder para resolver isso. Já fiz praticamente tudo e nada resolve.

Eu tenho as entradas *MX* e *TXT* do Google tanto no meu *Route 53* quanto no *Registro.br* configuradas.

PS.: Uso os serviços do Google para empresas e meu sistema esta em uma instância da AWS.

Comment: Vanderson, achei confusa sua pergunta. Você fala Google, mas o título indica que você quer enviar pela AWS. Detalhe melhor sua pergunta, colocando também a mensagem de retorno contendo o erro.

Comment: Eu uso os serviços do Google para empresas, o erro que aparece é de retorno de e-mail, como se o email estivesse errado.

Comment: Mas mas o que queres dizer com AWS?

Comment: Tenho uma instancia da AWS, uso o SES para os e-mails

Comment: Sem o domínio nem a tabela de DNS completa fica difícil saber, mas vc configurou o domínio certinho no painel do google?